# Navigation Controller throws error when i do push view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code in "Settings" view controller. This code allows me to hide navigation controller in main tab bar pages

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
 }
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
 }
```

when I use ***present*** function, it works fine; But when I use ***push*** func it throws error

```
func goToSlectedPage(){
        let vc = AboutController()
        //present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

The error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please file a radar on
>   UIKit if you see this assertion.'

I need to use push func and show the navigation controller in internal views. I am stuck here since yesterday, any help?

Comment: Please add some more informatino, if i understand what you are trying to do it's pretty simple, so you shouldn't get this print. Where is the `goToSlectedPage()` func declared?

Comment: all these 3 func are in "SettingsController" and i am trying to push "AboutController"

Comment: And `self.navigationController` is not nil? in the `goToSlectedPage` func?

Comment: @YuviGr no it's not null, i checked that.

Comment: Without any more information there isn't alot i can do to help. Do you have this project in a repo? i can look into it

Comment: @YuviGr i can upload it to you, give me 1 minute

Comment: @YuviGr can you share your email with me ? so i sent it to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152947/discussion-between-yuvigr-and-dotfreelancer).

Comment: @YuviGr you couldn't find the bug?

Comment: Not yet, still checking

Comment: @YuviGr I appreciate that

Comment: @YuviGr finally, I fixed it.. it was navigation code in app delegate class

Comment: post the answer and accept it user will know the problem